# How can I output sequence of number in descending order when the first input is higher than the second input vice versa?

Tags: vb.net

This one is working but it only output a sequence of number in ascending order even if the First Input is higher than the Second Input.

Here is what I want to happen

Ascending Order when

First Input: 2

Second Input: 8

Result 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Descending Orden when

First Input: 9

Second Input: 6

Result: 9, 8, 7, 6

```
 Private Sub btnAccept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click
    Dim A = txtstart.Text
    Dim B = txtend.Text

    Dim Start, Ending As Integer

    If A < B Then
        Start = A
        Ending = B
    Else
        Start = B
        Ending = A
    End If

    While Start <= Ending
        lblbetween1.Text = lblbetween1.Text & Start & " , "
        Start += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe lose the Start & Ending variables, keep the A<B test but have two loops.  One loop you have and is working, so think about what to do in the other (e.g. subtract by one each time instead of adding).  Hopefully that should help you solve this yourself

Answer (score 1):

With a [`For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) loop, you can choose the increment, so you can check which order the numbers are in and set the increment appropriately, for example:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Text

' ....

Private Sub btnAccept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click
    Dim a = Integer.Parse(txtStart.Text)
    Dim b = Integer.Parse(txtEnd.Text)

    Dim inc As Integer = -1

    If a < b Then
        inc = 1
    End If

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For i = a To b Step inc
        sb.Append(i & " , ")
    Next

    lblbetween1.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

Fortunately, this still works if the numbers are equal, so there is no need for a special case for that.

It's better to use a StringBuilder to concatenate lots of strings, instead of just using `&` on lots of strings or the content of a control.

[`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) makes sure that the program doesn't try to do things with possibly unexpected results such as adding a number to a string. You should set it as the default for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Will need to add

```
Imports System.Linq
```

and then

```
Dim a = 10I
Dim b = 15I

Dim start = Math.Min(a, b)
Dim count = Math.Max(a, b) - start

Dim series = Enumerable.Range(start, count + 1).ToList

If b < a Then
  series.Reverse()
End If

Dim result = String.Join(",", series)
```